# Ajax POST is not set yet still activates part of a php if-statement

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap-4

In trying to use Ajax to POST data from page1 to page2, an if statement on page2 lets me know that `$_POST` is not set - but despite the condition not being met, it still runs some, *but not all* of the code.
The problem persists on both XAMPP and my web-server.

Button on page1 to POST data:

```
<button type="button" class="btn postBtn" onclick="location.href='page2.php'" id="1337">Click me</button>
```

Sending data through ajax on page1:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.postBtn').click(function(){            
    var id = $(this).attr("id");  
    $.ajax({  
        url:"page2.php",  
        method:"post",  
        data:{
                id:id,
            },  
        });  
    });     
});
```

Php if statement on page2:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    echo $_POST['id'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
} else {
    echo "no id posted";
}
```

When clicking the button, i expect the if statement to echo `1337` and to set `$_SESSION['id'] = 1337`. 
However, when i actually click the button, the echo shows `no id posted`, but surprisingly `print_r($_SESSION)` shows `[id] => 1337`.

Any ideas of what i am missing?

Comment: Where specifically are you observing the text "no id posted"?  In your debugging tools or actually on the page?

Comment: Both the echo and the $_SESSION can be observed in both the debugging and on the actual page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ajax to post the value, remove onclick of your button. If you want to see the result you are echoing add success field in your ajax and console the result there.

```
$('.postBtn').click(function(){        
    var id = $(this).attr("id");  
    $.ajax({  
        url:"page2.php",  
        method:"post",  
        data:{id:id,},
        success: function(res) { 
            console.log(res);
        } 
    });  
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Following your instructions my console shows that both the ID is echoed + the session is set - great! Your answer made me realise that ajax does post the id, but that it occurs not like GET, or form-based post, but "behind the scenes". Just out of interest, could you elaborate on why i have to remove the onclick?

Comment: On second though it is of course because then you wouldt be able to check console. Brainfart.